# jQuery html() and normal text beside eachother

Tags: jquery, html

I have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JG3nj/

Why wont the text get beside the html from the function that do html(). There's no `<br>`that makes it go under the icon? Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is wrapped in a `div`. `div`s are `display: block` by default.

If you can't remove it, give the `div` a fixed width and `float: left`, or make it `display: inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Because a DIV is a block element.  Try using a SPAN or some CSS to make the DIV an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Because the icon is inside a div, which are block elements. Meaning, it creates a break after it.

Answer (score 0):

`s += '<span style="float:left"><img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-image/2724-16x16x32.png"></span>';`

instead of

```
 s += '<img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-image/2724-16x16x32.png">';
```

I just updated pls have a [look](http://jsfiddle.net/JG3nj/2/)